# Storybook mdx files are not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook, mdxjs

I use default Storybook Webpack config alongside with data from my existed one. I don't see any *.mdx files in a stories side-bar.

At first I just have replaced all `config.module.rules` by rules from existed webpack config and I got this error: [Unexpected default error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssDBE.png)

```
Error: Unexpected default export without title: undefined
    at http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:96519:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:96512:11
    at ConfigApi.configure (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:76149:7)
    at Object.configure (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:96643:17)
    at configure (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:95240:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:6006/main.iframe.bundle.js:18:36)
    at Object../.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (http://localhost:6006/main.iframe.bundle.js:19:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:854:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:151:20)
```

Then I added this loader for *.mdx files:

```
{
  test: /\.(stories|story)\.mdx$/, use: [
    require.resolve('@mdx-js/loader'),
  ]
}
```

Hence, the error disappeared but also *.mdx files are not displayed.
I tried to add "babel-loader" before "@mdx-js/loader" in this way:

```
  {
    test: /\.(stories|story)\.mdx$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'],
        },
      },
      {
        loader: '@mdx-js/loader',
        options: {
          compilers: [createMDXCompiler({})],
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

Also I checked different order for rules in `config.module.rules` and I added this rule directly to existed "webpack.config". I noticed that it doesn't matter what loader is in "mdx" rule, for instance, this works without errors but the files still not displayed:

```
{
   test: /\.(stories|story)\.mdx$/, 
   use: ['any text]
};
```

mdx file sample:

```
import { Preview, IconGallery, IconItem } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
...
import { appConfig } from '../../config/AppConfig';

<Meta title='Theming/Icons' />

# Icons

<AppConfigContext.Provider value={appConfig}>
  <IconGallery>
    <IconItem name='ArrowDown'>
      <Icon variant='ArrowDown' />
    </IconItem>
    ...
</AppConfigContext.Provider>
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const sites = require('./sites');

const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');

const appPackageJson = require(paths.appPackageJson);

// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';

const webpackDevClientEntry = require.resolve(
  'react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'
);
const reactRefreshOverlayEntry = require.resolve(
  'react-dev-utils/refreshOverlayInterop'
);

// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const emitErrorsAsWarnings = process.env.ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS === 'true';
const disableESLintPlugin = process.env.DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN === 'true';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);

const SITE = process.env.SITE?.toLowerCase() || sites[0];
if (!sites.includes(SITE)) {
  throw new Error(
    `Value of SITE: ${SITE} is not valid value. Please use one of the following [${sites.toString()}]`
  );
}
// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// Get the path to the uncompiled service worker (if it exists).
const swSrc = paths.swSrc;

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

const hasJsxRuntime = (() => {
  if (process.env.DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM === 'true') {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    require.resolve('react/jsx-runtime');
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
})();
const getRegexForIgnoreStyles = (app) => {
  const test = new RegExp(
    `\\.(${sites.filter((site) => site !== app).join('|')})\\.scss`
  );

  return { test, loader: require.resolve('ignore-loader') };
};
// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Variable used for enabling profiling in Production
  // passed into alias object. Uses a flag if passed into the build command
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');

  // We will provide `paths.publicUrlOrPath` to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  const shouldUseReactRefresh = env.raw.FAST_REFRESH;

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {}
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: { ...cssOptions, url: false }
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009'
              },
              stage: 3
            }),
            // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
            // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
            // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
            postcssNormalize()
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment
        }
      }
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      const options = { sourceMap: true };
      if (preProcessor === 'sass-loader') {
        options.additionalData = `$assets-url: '${process.env.REACT_APP_ASSETS_URL}';`;
      }
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
            root: paths.appSrc
          }
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };
  const baseConfig = { 
    ... 
  }

  ...
    
  const baseRules = {
    // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
    // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
    // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
    oneOf: [
      // TODO: Merge this config once `image/avif` is in the mime-db
      // https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db
      {
        test: [/\.avif$/],
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
          mimetype: 'image/avif',
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
      // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
      // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      // Process application JS with Babel.
      // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          customize: require.resolve(
            'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
          ),
          presets: [
            [
              require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
              {
                runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic'
              }
            ]
          ],

          plugins: [
            [
              require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
              {
                loaderMap: {
                  svg: {
                    ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]'
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          ],
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true,
          // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
          cacheCompression: false,
          compact: isEnvProduction
        }
      },
      // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
      // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
        exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          babelrc: false,
          configFile: false,
          compact: false,
          presets: [
            [
              require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
              { helpers: true }
            ]
          ],
          cacheDirectory: true,
          // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
          cacheCompression: false,

          // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
          // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
          // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
          sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
          inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
        }
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
      // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
      // of CSS.
      // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
      {
        test: cssRegex,
        exclude: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment
        }),
        // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
        // containing package claims to have no side effects.
        // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
        // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
        sideEffects: true
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
      // using the extension .module.css
      {
        test: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
          modules: {
            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
          }
        })
      },
      // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
      // By default we support SASS Modules with the
      // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
      {
        test: sassRegex,
        exclude: sassModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders(
          {
            importLoaders: 3,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ),
        // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
        // containing package claims to have no side effects.
        // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
        // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
        sideEffects: true
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
      // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
      {
        test: sassModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders(
          {
            importLoaders: 3,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
            modules: {
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        )
      },
      // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
      // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
      // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
      // that fall through the other loaders.
      {
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
        // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
        // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
        // by webpacks internal loaders.
        exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|ejs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ]
  };

  const configs = sites
    .map((brand) => {
      return {
        ...baseConfig,
        name: brand,
        entry: isEnvProduction
          ? { [brand]: paths.appIndexJs }
          : [paths.appIndexJs],
        module: {
          ...baseConfig.module,
          rules: [
            ...baseConfig.module.rules,
            {
              oneOf: [getRegexForIgnoreStyles(brand), ...baseRules.oneOf]
            }
          ]
        },
        plugins: [...baseConfig.plugins].filter(Boolean)
      };
    })
    .reduce((acc, item) => {
      return { ...acc, [item.name]: item };
    }, {});

  return isEnvProduction ? [...Object.values(configs)] : configs[SITE];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the main thing was that `*.mdx` files are loaded successfully using only default Storybook config, hence it excludes any syntax errors. And as a final decision I just removed all `*.mdx` files from Storybook and created new `*.tsx` in target Storybook list block with the same content using all needed additional styles.

Answer (score -2):

### TL;DR

- obey to Storybook's default `*.stories.mdx` naming convention
- ensure that there is no trailing `;` behind your `<Meta title="..." />` tag – something like this **breaks the story**: `<Meta title="..." />;`
- also it seems that stories inside hidden folders (folder-name starting with a `.` – e.g. `.stories/my.stories.ts`) will be ignored as well. Remove the `.` from the folder name in those cases
- when you add some html-tags (e.g. `<br/>`) after a `<Story>` or `<Canvas>` (or any other storybook-mdx-component, make sure to add a line-break between the `<Story>` and your `<br/>`. Otherwise this will also cause an error, making the file disappear.

### Detail

In my case the problem was that I didn't want to go with Storybook's default naming convention `*.stories.mdx`. I tried to omit the `.stories` part (i.e. having files like `button.mdx` instead of `button.stories.mdx`) and reconfigured the `main.js` accordingly. But this seems to not work – no mdx-files were showing up. Once I reverted back to `.stories.mdx` the mdx files were displayed again in the storybook side-bar.

### Update

Another problem I noticed is very subtle and easy to miss. If you or your code formatter by any chance added a `;` after your `<Meta title="...">` tag, your file will not be shown in the sidebar. So keep an eye on that:

```html
<!-- note the trailing ";" -->
<Meta title="My/Title" />; 
<!-- after removing it, your file will show again -->
<Meta title="My/Title" />
```

Comment: This solved my issue for storybook 6.5.13